# Why does this function return 0 all the time?

Tags: c, return

I've got a rather weird problem with my tick-tac-toe game. I've set up a very simple mechanism which allows for (almost) flawless gameplay. At the moment of writing this post, I struggle with preventing the user from using input for inappropiate purposes (such as overwriting taken spots). I've tried to put a simple if statement in my function called ruch, which is responsbile for overwriting the array wynik(which by the way stores the data). Here's the function itself:

```
int ruch(char pole, bool gracz){
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        if(gracz==true)
        {
            if(pole==i+1)
            {
                if(wynik[i]=='#')
                {
                    wynik[i]='X';
                    return 3;
                }
                else if(wynik[i]!='#')
                    return 0;
            }
        }
        else if(gracz==false)
        {
            if(pole==i+1)
            {
                if(wynik[i]=='#')
                {
                    wynik[i]='O';
                    return 3;
                }
                else if(wynik[i]!='#')
                    return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the whole code: http://pastebin.com/zNHHpHA1

As you can see, the logic behind the return is rather smple- if ruch notices an unwanted behaviour, it will prompt user to re-evaluate his move:

```
    while(ruch(input,ruc)==0){
        printf("Wprowadzono złą liczbę!\n");
        scanf("%d", &input);
        ruch(input, ruc);}
```

However, the ruch function returns 0 regardless of the input. I think that is the only obstacle that holds my code back from functioning (rather) properly. Thank you in advance for any help. 
I am not a native english speaker, so bear with me.

Comment: This formatting is hard to read. Don't try making C look like Python or whatever you try here!

Comment: Does your code compile? It seems as though your method, `ruch`, has the possibility of not returning anything.

Comment: Yes, once I cleaned up the braces that becomes obvious, and I suspect that's what's happening.

Comment: @Olaf Yeah, I will try to work on that aspect. I am still a beginner (although that is not a excuse!)

Comment: So, the for loop is unneeded as it only actually does anything when `pole == i+1`, not to mention the wierd `else if ...` idiom

Comment: @JonnyHenly Yes, it does. I haven't included the basic option since 'ruch' should always return something. I will try to include default option though.

Comment: @JonnyHenly: C does not support _methods_, only _functions_.

Comment: This returns 3 if `wynik[pole-1] == '#'`, other wise it returns either zero or random data (if pole > 9, or pole < 1).

Comment: @Olaf I assumed the two were synonymous, I was wrong. You learn something new every day.

Comment: @kdopen That has been my intention since the very beginning. Unless I have overlooked something in my thought process, that is the valid path to take. I am a noob though, so could you please elaborate on whether it is a good behaviour?

Comment: @PiotrOsiewicz the whole function comes down to `if (wynik[pole-1] == '#') {wynik[pole-1] = (gracz) ? 'X' : 'O'; return 3; } return 0;`

Comment: @PiotrOsiewicz there's actually a lot of things that can be done in order to improve your code. Though it's perfectly ok for a beginner, you may want to submit your code to Code Review stackexchange to get the detailed review.

Comment: @kdopen Alright, I see what you mean. Thank you for taking your time to enlighten me on the matter. You guys have really sparked my motivation to code now! One more question though - is my code as bad (format-wise) as Olaf has mentioned? While I understand that there are as many tastes as there are styles of formating, I also get the feeling that there are few do's and do not's which I've broken in my code. While I am relatively unexperienced, I would not like to get bad habits at the very beginning of my journey.

Comment: @Vovanrock2002 Yes, I understood it from the very start. My plan was to create a code which could be functional (and it was, until I tried to fix some of the forementioned bugs) and then start to improve and optimise it. Thanks to you guys I can finally start the second part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pastebin, in lines 44-46 and 54-58, you call `ruch` thrice with the same input. Hence the second and the third call will always return 0.

Change

```
ruch(input,ruc);
printf("%d", ruch(input,ruc));
while(ruch(input, ruc)==0) {
  printf("Wprowadzono złą liczbę!\n");
  scanf("%d", &input);
  ruch(input, ruc);
}
```

to something like

```
int result = ruch(input, ruc);
printf("%d", result);
while(result == 0) {
  printf("Wprowadzono złą liczbę!\n");
  scanf("%d", &input);
  result = ruch(input, ruc);
}
```

Comment: @PiotrOsiewicz at your service, pane programista (oh I hope I spelled it correctly)

Comment: I am not quite there yet. However, you have to take one step at a time, therefore I do not blame myself for not being fully knowledgable on the topic. Also, you were almost right. In polish you would say "panie programisto". Don't worry though - it's one of the hardest languages to learn and understand (grammar-wise).

Comment: @PiotrOsiewicz if you have other questions regarding your game I'd suggest to create several new posts. Asked this way, it's more convenient for the community to answer.